# What is $x$ in the formula?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

What is $x$ (assume it's integer) in $512p+ 1 = x^3$, **where $p$ is a prime number.**

Attempt:

$$a^3 - b^3 = (a-b) (a^2 + ab+b^2) \Longrightarrow 512p = x^3 -1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1).$$

Here I got stuck. Am I suppose to plug in $p$ and try it one by one?

---

What about $16p + 1 = x^3$??

Comment: Don't know if it helps but $512=8^3$

Comment: $x^2+x+1$ is odd and $512 = 2^9$.

Comment: My friend was suggesting me to use the formula

Comment: @Χpẘ,p is a prime number though. This means that it can't be 1

Comment: That's right. It also means that $x= 513, p=263683$ won't work either.

Comment: I think $(x-1)$ must be a divisible by $512$ thus $2^9k + 1 = x$. Also $x^2 + x + 1$ is divisible by $p$ or $(2^{9}k + 1)^2 + (2^{9}k + 1)  + 1 = 2^{18}k^2 + 2^{10}k + 1 + 2^{9}k + 2$. So I think we need to find a prime or prime multiple of form   $2^{18}k^2 + 2^{10}k + 1 + 2^{9}k + 2$.

Comment: I checked for all $x \leq 10000$ and while there are $19$ values of $x$ that meet the condition. In all $19$ cases $p$ was composite. Given A---B's comment means $k>80$

Comment: It is a little bit naughty to change your post. Etiquette says add an EDIT ... if you want to change the question... now $x=17$ & $p=307$ ...

Comment: I would say somebody to rollback the edit.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit thanks for pointing that out. I was still using $512$ from the old post.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I was trying to write a programming script to see if I can get a solution.

Comment: Now, is it 512 or 16? Please clarify the question.

Comment: So $p=513^2+513+1=263683=7 \times 139 \times 271 $ ... that is not prime ?

Comment: Here's a powershell script I've been using: 2..10000|?{(\$_*\$_*\$_-1)%16 -eq 0}|?{\$p=(\$_*\$_*\$_-1)/16;\$p%2 -and \$p%3 -and \$p%5 -and \$p%7 -and \$p%11 -and \$p%13 -and \$p%17 -and \$p%19 -and \$p%23 -and \$p%29 -and \$p%31 -and \$p%37}|%{"\$_  \$((\$_*\$_*\$_-1)/16)"}. Which you can use on recent versions of Windows. Note my poor man's prime filter which only catches some primes. You have to check $x$s it lets through manually (or replace it with a real filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$512p=2^9p=x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. Note that $x^3$ is odd (and hence $x$ is odd) since it's an even number plus $1$. When $x$ is odd, then $x^2+x+1$ is also odd and $x-1$ is the only even factor which implies that $p=x^2+x+1$ and $2^9=x-1$ (otherwise $p$ would not be prime or odd). Hence, the only possible solution could be $2^9=x-1\implies x=2^9+1\implies p=(2^9+1)^2+2^9+2$ which is not prime (it's divisible by $7$). Hence, there are no solutions where $p$ must be prime.

Comment: What about 16p +1 = x^3

Comment: It's the same idea since $2^4=16$'s only prime factor is $2$. In that case, you get $x=2^4+1=17\implies p=307$ (is that a prime?)

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. $x^2+x+1 =x(x+1)+1$ is always odd..... So if $2^9p=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ then $2^9|\;(x-1)$ so $x=1+2^9k$ and $p=k (x^2+x+1).$  But $p$ is prime so $k$ must be $1$ and $x=513.$.... But $513=7(73)+2$ so  $513^2+513+1\equiv 2^2+2+1\equiv 0 \pmod 7.$

Comment: @user254665 thank you for the confirmation. I really appreciate it.

Comment: How did you know $p$ is divisible by 7? Were you able to do it by inspection or did you use a calculator?

Comment: @lamanon You do not need a calculator. Consider what $2^9\pmod{7}$ is and find out if that last expression for $p$ is $0$ mod $7$. If so, that means it's divisible by 7. Hint: $2^9 = 2^3 * 2^3 * 2 = 8 * 8 * 2$.

Comment: I think you meant $2^9 = 2^3 * 2^3 * 2^3 = 8 * 8 * 8$

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Since $512p+ 1 = x^3$, we know that $x^3$ is odd, so that $x$ must be odd.

When you have factored it into $512p = x^3 -1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, since $x$ is odd, $x^2+x+1$ is odd, so $x-1$ must be some multiple of 512. However, if $x-1$ is not exactly 512, $p$ won't be a prime. So we have $x-1 = 512$, hence $x=513$. Substitute this solution back, you will find that $p$ is not a prime, so this equation has no solution when $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 1):

$512p + 1 = x^3$

$512p = x^3 -1$

$512p = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$

$8^3p = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$

If $x$ is even then $x^2 + x + 1$ is odd, and $x-1$ is odd and LHS is odd.  That's impossible.

So $x$ is odd.  So $x^2 + x + 1$ is odd.  So $512|x-1$

$p = \frac {x-1}{512}(x^2 + x + 1)$.

If $x \le 0$ then $ \frac {x-1}{512}(x^2 + x + 1) < 0$ so that's a contradiction, so $x^2 + x + 1 > 1$

$p$ is prime. So it only has $1$ and $p$ as factors.  So $x^2 + x + 1 = p$ or $x^2 + x+1=1$.  The later is impossible so $\frac {x-1}{512} = 1$ and $x^2 + x+1 = p$... That is, if there is any answer at all.

So $x = 513$ and $p =513^2 + 513 +1$... if, such a number is prime.  If not, there is no solution.

Comment: Not my point.  x^2 + x + 1  and x-1/512 are factors of p.  p only has two factors, 1 and p.  x^2 + x + 1 ne 1.  So x^2 + x + 1 = p.  so x-1/512=1

Comment: Did you forget p is prime? And x is an integer.  p *cant* have any factors but 1 and itself.

Comment: What about 16p +1 = x^3

Comment: Try using the answers here as a guide on how to approach $16p+1=x^3$. It should be fairly similar so give it a try. If you run into an issue, just edit your original post with your process and we can help you.

Comment: What about 16 p+1 = x^3?  then 16p = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)? x is odd so 16|(x-1) so $p = \frac {x-1}{16} (x^2 + x + 1)$. $p$ is prime and $x^2 + x+1)>1$ so x^2 + x+1 = p and (x-1)/16 = 1.  so x = 17.  And p = 17 ^2 + 17 + 1 = 307$.  Same thing.  Of course it's possible x^2 + x + 1 is not prime.  In that case $2Mp + 1 = x^3$ is a false statement.  That's impossible if x^2 + x + 1 is not prime and p is.  And if p isn't prime there mayb be other factorings.

Answer (score 1):

suppose first: $x=2k,  k\in \mathbb{Z}$; then

$$(2k-1)[2(k^2+k)+1] = 512p \\ \implies \text{No such } p \text{ exists where } (2k-1)  \& [2(k^2+k)+1] \text{ are odd numbers.}$$

suppose second: $x=2k+1, k\in \mathbb{Z}$; then

$$(2k)[2(k^2+k)+1] = 512p $$
$$ (k)[2(k^2+k)+1] = 256p $$
$$ \text{where } [2(k^2+k)+1] \text{ is an odd number.} \implies k=256, p = 2(k^2+k)+1  \\ \implies p=263683 \quad \textbf{dividable by 7, so, not acceptable.} $$

$$\implies \text{No such } p \text{ exists.}$$

For: $16p+1 = x^3$

$$(x-1)(x^2+x+1) = 16p$$

where $x^2+x+1$ is an odd number, so: $x=17$ and $p=307$ which is a prime number.

Comment: What about 16p +1 = x^3

Comment: @wrek: you can check the answer again.